# Liferay Commerce Mini Cart Remove All Items event listener is not working

Tags: liferay, event-listener, commerce, minicart, liferay-commerce

I am working with Liferay DXP 7.3 and Commerce 3.0. (GA1)

I would like to listen event Remove All Items on Mini Cart, but the event is not triggered.
This is my code:

```
Liferay.on('productRemovedFromCart', getCartTotal);
```

Does any one know how can I listen to this event?

[image: mini-cart image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `'product-removed-from-cart'`.
The payload will include the removed product sku.

Here's the code which fires the event:

```js
Liferay.fire(PRODUCT_REMOVED_FROM_CART, {
    skuId: 111111,
});
```

Just use a dash cases rather than camel cases ;)

Comment: Hi @Fabio, thank you for your answer. With LR DXP 7.3 and Commerce 3.0. I can not find 'product-removed-from-cart', only available 'productRemovedFromCart'